# HttpClient with Selenium or HTMLUNIT?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Alright, so I'm in a small pickle. I'm running into issues with JSoup since the page needs Javascript to to finish loading some of the page. Fortunately, I've worked around it in the past (parsed the raw javascript code), and it's very tedious. As of late, I tried to make a program to login to a website but it requires a token from a  element. That form element is not visible unless JavaScript is executed, so it wont show up at all for me to even extract. So I decided to look into Selenium.

First question, is this the library I should be looking into? The reason why I'm so bent on using HttpClient is because some of these websites are very high in traffic and doesn't load up all the way **BUT** I don't need these pages to load up all the way. I just need it to load up enough to where I can retrieve the login token. I prefer to communicate with the webserver with raw JSON/POST methods once I discover the the methods required vs. having Selenium automate a click/wait/type sequence.

Basically, I only need selenium to load up 1/4 of the page, just to retrieve request tokens. The rest of my program will send POST methods using HttpClient.

Or should I just let selenium do all the work? My goal is speed. I need to login, purchase an item fast.

Edit: Actually, I might go with HtmlUnit because it's very minimal. I only need to scrape information, and I don't want to run Selenium's StandAlone Server. Is this the better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, HtmlUnit is quicker than Selenium so if you are going for speed you should use that. Anyway, keep in mind that Selenium has its own implementation of HtmlUnitDriver. So, as another option, you could use Selenium with HtmlUnit. The difference between them is that HtmlUnit is a browser itself without GUI, meanwhile Selenium works calling browsers feature. You may want to take a look at this other question for further details: [Selenium vs HtmlUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807689/selenium-vs-htmlunit)