# hide the webpage in selenium webdriver while testing

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

While running the test in selenium Webdriver using JAVA, I do not want the webpage to be seen on the screen. Is there a way that the program runs and the webpage is not seen.

Comment: You could try using PhantomJS driver.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the budget for a dedicated machine to run tests, then a simple trick is to launch the browser off-screen:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--window-position=-32000,-32000");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this like below Use HtmlUnitDriver it opens your web page in headless mode i.e no visibility of any web page for more info about html unit driver please visit

```
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.html
```

also `visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807689/selenium-vs-htmlunit`

Now back to question

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// do some action with html unit driver
// for example open google home page
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
// now verify that google home page is loaded properly
System.out.println("Printing Title of the Google Home Page : " + driver.getTitle());

// above line prints on console : Printing Title of the Google Home Page : Google
```