# How to use addCustomRequestHeader method in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to use addCustomRequestHeader method to set a custom header for selenium requests. Given below is the source code

```
       Selenium sel = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://www.google.com");
       sel.start("addCustomRequestHeader=true");
//  sel.start();
    sel.addCustomRequestHeader("mycustomheader","automation");
    sel.open("http://www.google.com/");
```

This code didn't add the header to the request. I tried to look up the request headers using Fiddler. Does any one here know what am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does it work for any custom header or only supported known HTTP headers? That is, perhaps it behaves more like an addRequestHeader().

Comment: Try by setting Selenium as a proxy server and it is discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442405/how-to-use-addcustomrequestheader-properly

Answer (score 3):

You need to start the selenium in proxy injection mode

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -proxyInjectionMode
```

You can then add custom requests headers like this (in Python)

```
sel.start("addCustomRequestHeader=true")
sel.add_custom_request_header("mycustomheader","automation")
sel.open('http://www.google.com')
```

To see if the custom header has been applied, check the tab that has the selenium server running. You should see something like this in the console messages

```
INFO - Command request: addCustomRequestHeader[mycustomheader, automation] on session 
INFO - Got result: OK on session
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, running selenium in proxy injection mode is not acceptable so I have followed the approach of 'ModHeader' chrome extension to set the custom headers. This approached worked fine for me.

```
ModHeader Extension: https://github.com/mdamien/chrome-extensions-archive
```

Here is the code snippet

```
ChromeOptions chromeOpt = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOpt.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.args", "--disable-logging");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");

chromeOpt.addExtensions(new File("./ModHeader_v2.2.3.crx"));

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOpt);

// set the context on the extension so the localStorage can be accessed
driver.get("chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/icon.png");

// setup ModHeader with two headers (token1 and token2)
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
"localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify([{                " +
"  title: 'Selenium', hideComment: true, appendMode: '',           " +
"  headers: [                                                      " +
"    {enabled: true, name: 'token1', value: 'testHeaderValue1', comment: ''}, " +
"    {enabled: true, name: 'token2', value: 'testHeaderValue2', comment: ''}  " +
"  ],                                                              " +
"  respHeaders: [],                                                " +
"  filters: []                                                     " +
"}]));                                                             ");
driver.navigate().to("https://localhost:8443");
```

Fiddler Custom header snapshot
[image: Fiddler Custom header snapshot]